Maui WebView ViewPort issues on iOS
I'm new to Maui development and trying to get some web content loading in the WebView on iOS.
All of the content/scripts are loading fine but the sizing when running on iPhone seems to be assuming that the screen resolution is much higher.
I've tried adding:
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1' />

or an explicit smaller viewport:
<meta name='viewport' content='width=375,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1' />

These appear to have no impact at all on what is rendered when my local html files are loaded in.
Incorrect sizing from html loaded from resources:

Interestingly if I start the WebView with some embedded HTML it's sizing it correctly but as soon as I navigate to any other page it's back to rendering a full width page instead of the mobile responsive version.
Correct sizing on HTML defined within the web view in the XAML file.

Are there other settings on the WebView I need to set to tell it how to behave?

Please provide a minimal reproducible example and elaborate on the problem by showing the relevant code and what the issue looks like.
